# Diferença entre process e immediate

Tags: jsf, primefaces

em JSF, qual a diferença dos atributos immediate e process? A meu ponto de vista ambos parecem ter funções parecidas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom, segundo a documentação do **PrimeFaces 6.0**:

O atributo ***immediate*** tem seu valor *default* = `false` e seu tipo é  `boolean`.
Sua função é determinar em qual fase do ciclo de vida do **JSF** o componente será processado, se o valor do atributo for `true` a ação será processada na fase **apply_request_values**, se for `false` será processada na fase **invoke_application**.

O atributo **process** tem seu valor *default* = `null` e seu tipo é **`String`**.
Sua função é fazer com que o JSF "pule" o processamento de todos os componentes que não são abrangidos pelo atributo **process**.

Comment: É interessante destacar que o atributo process pode fazer várias ações diferentes , entre elas this, all, none,parent, form, todos precedidos de arroba,  cada uma para um tipo de necessidade diferente.